# Is this phenomenon capacitive coupling or human antenna effect?

Tags: antenna, mains, capacitance, electromagnetic, coupling

I injected a 90 MHz signal into an electrical cable via a signal generator. And I used a spectrum analyzer to measure the signal strength of 90 MHz at the other end of the cable. Then I found the measurement changed when I was walking around in the room. The changes were not so large, but detectable.

I have been told that the human body can pick up the radio frequency signal as it is a conductor. But I am not sure why the signal along the cable also changes [image]

Comment: Motion detection alarms have used this technology with a  splitter, diode and peak detector to detect intrusions  for at least 40yrs. This more sensitive than transmission path.

Comment: What is the cable type? How long is the cable? What are the connectors? N, SMA, TNC, BNC, etc.? And are you sure the connectors are secure and not cross-threaded? If you’re using the right cable, and the cable is not ridiculously long (and moving over air conditioner vents, and such), then I’m with you - I wouldn’t expect this either.

Comment: My question may not clear. So I put a picture above. The connector is self-designed by refitting an SMA connector. And the sensor is based on a sony radio.

Comment: This experiment is inspired by the FM radio reception may change if people are changing their positions in the room. https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1201283

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a very well-shielded coax, or the coax is poorly terminated, or the wiring to the shield-braid is broken or long and thus has lots of inductance.

These conditions are making the SHIELD be hot. At 90MHz, wavelength is 3.3 meters, and quarterwave is 0.8 meters or 32 inches. Quarterwave antennas can serve as impedance transformers between infinity and Zero, thus generating very high voltages at one end and very high currents at the other end.

Summary: your cable, connectors, pigtails, braids and terminations are suspect.

Comment: Sorry. My statement may not clear. It's not a coax, but the line of a strip. I have put a picture above.

Answer (score 0):

the body is reflecting part of the signal back to the cable

the system is working like a primitive RADAR

so human antenna effect.

Comment: Primitive RADAR? Thanks. I will check that.

Comment: I have read some materials about radar. (1) I found that radar has a transmitter and receiver. Transmitter sends a signal out and the receiver receives the reflected signal. But in my case, there is only one cable. (2) The signal I injected is 90 MHz whose wavelength is 3.3m which is comparable to the height of a human. But in radar principle, " if the wavelength is much shorter than the target's size, the wave will bounce off in a way similar to the way light is reflected by a mirror." I don't think 90 MHz can get a good reflection in my case. Could you please help me explain these?